# Use JavaScript functions on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, datetime

I am using a DateTime field on a Visualforce page which gets its value from the controller. I would like to know if I can use JavaScript or jQuery code directly on the Visualforce page to convert this DateTime Field (DT) to a date field on page load.

I know the JavaScript function is DT.format('MMMM d,  yyyy'), but I need some idea on how to implement this.

#### My Page

```
<apex:page controller="dateTime_custom">
    {!date}
</apex:page>
```

#### Controller

```
public class dateTime_custom {
    public datetime getdate(){
        return DateTime.Now();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to convert it in javascript? You could convert the datetime to date in apex and format it to string and associate it to a getter variable and access it in javascript. This is a better approach as you wouldn't have to worry about the locale,dateformate etc..

Comment: ya I was able to convert in apex but interested in knowing if there is any simple solution using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `param` tag and customize the output to the date format. This works. Happy coding.

```
<apex:page controller="dateTime_custom">
    <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
        <apex:param value="{!date}" />
    </apex:outputText> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer and provide a sample?

Comment: Hi Suri. Can you please show that on above example as I am new to this community

Comment: <apex:page controller="dateTime_custom">
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!date}" />
</apex:outputText> 
</apex:page> I paseted the same in answer block but it is not showing up. so weired.

Comment: Thanks Suri. That worked perfectly. Even though not javascript, I am looking to do this from VF page just as you shown in your example. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Suri, Would like to know if we can change the time zone from GMT to other timezone using your code as I am getting only GMT eventhough input is GMT+5:30. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign your apex date variable to some javascript variable you can do it just by creating a new Date with your apex variable as parameter:

```
<script>
    var d = new Date('{!date}');
    console.log('d: ' + d);
    console.log('day: ' + d.getDate());
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the following and got this. <script>
    var d = new Date('{!date}');
    console.log('d: ' + d);
    console.log('day: ' + d.getDate());   alert(d.getDate()+'/'+ d.getMonth()+'/'+d.getYear());
</script>   but I recevied the o/p has 28/3/115 what I am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

This should generally work:

```
var date = new Date("{!date}");
```

However, this may not be fully compatible with all browsers, so I'd suggest using DateTime.getTime() in Apex Code, then using that value:

```
var date = new Date({!timestamp});
```

You could also serialize it into JSON, then use native JSON methods in the browser to parse. Only modern browsers support this method.